# What can counter ice magic that's not fire magic?

Tags: magic

In this world, there is concept magic -- such as fire magic, ice magic, light magic, and wind magic.

The simplest way to fight a particular concept is to pit its opposite against it -- light vs. shadow -- but wizards can also try to use concept magic that is not its polar opposite, such as trying having wind magic blow out a fire like a candle, or earth magic trying to smother it.  Though this can fail -- you might fan the fire instead of blowing it out.

A master of fire magic hid a work about it in a location protected by ice magic, in order that only another master of fire magic could find it.  What sort of concept magic could be used instead of fire magic?  (There is no heat or cold magic.)

Comment: *"What sort of concept magic could be used instead of fire magic?"* Retrieving magic. Phase-changing magic. Sublimation magic. Liquefaction magic. Transportation magic. Translocation magic. Teleportation magic. Delegation magic. Piercing magic. Shattering magic. Tunneling magic. Superposition magic. Fetching magic. Universal magic. Leasing magic. Vibratory magic. Incorporeal magic. Geometric magic. Topologic magic. Safe-breaking magic. Dislocation magic. Planckian magic. Black magic. White magic. Wish-granting magic. Unprotecting magic. Uncovering magic. Discovering magic.

Comment: Ok AlexP, we are taking that to the next poem slam after covid is done.  You find your beret.  I will tune my bongos and back you up.

Comment: Given that I gave specific examples of the concepts involved, @AlexP, what is the point of your comment?

Comment: I have examples of the concepts hidden behind the *etc.* which ends the list given in the question. *Etc.* is a very powerful word.

Comment: Actually it means "on the same principle," so no, they aren't, but -- all right, then, I eliminated it.  I trust that answers your objection to the question? @AlexP

Comment: (1) *Et caetera* means "and others". (2) I don't see why translocation magic is any less *"concept magic"* than light magic. If anything, translocation is a more conceptual concept than light, which, in the end, is a concrete phenomenon. (3) Shadow is not the opposite of light, or, at least, it is not *necessarily* the opposite of light. (4) All the concepts listed in my comment can indeed be used to get access to an object protected by a barrier of ice. (5) This is why the question is considered opinion based.

Comment: The concepts in your concept magic are natural things. I tend to think of concepts as ideas & not things. I suggest water magic could overcome ice magic or light magic if it can be high-intensity light magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tome is locked behind a permanent wall of ice over which a frigid waterfall constantly flows.  The water is so cold that even the most powerful fire magic cannot boil it out of the way such that more fire magic can then melt the ice.
The key is to combine wind magic with a bag of salt.
Use the wind magic to blow the salt up to the top of the waterfall where it can mix with the water and flow down onto the ice.  Although the salt is not itself magical, it is the antithesis of ice.  So when salt water meets ice, the ice melts.
Only in this way, can the book be freed from its container using the magic of one single discipline caster.